# Linux booting problem. Fsck and resize2fs won't work

Tags: filesystems, partition, fsck

I dual boot my pc with windows and linux. I preinstalled windows and after that I installed Linux. I installed it completly and lastly, restarted it.

When I restarted it I shows error

```
unexpected inconsistency; run fsck manually
```

I tried `fsck` with `force` but, won't work. `fsck` shows error

```
filesystem size is larger than physical size and either superblock
or the partition table is likely to be corrupt
```

So, I run `resize2fs` command and it shows `not found`

I tried `sudo` but it shows same error.

Please help me! What I relly need to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to unix SE and hi! The condition you present seems quite severe to me. Since you just installed. I guess you don't have personal data you fear to lose. You might want to reinstall, and watch for any warnings and signs of irregularities during the installation process. By the way, would you mind check your English spelling when posting?

Comment: Add the exact command lines you used to the question. *I run resize2fs* doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Something went severely wrong there. It makes little sense to try repairing the system before it is understood what has happened there. `resize2fs` is of no help in that situation because it cannot reduce a filesystem if it cannot access the last (used) part of it. You need to enlarge the underlying block device, not the filesystem.

You may have to boot from a different medium, perhaps your install medium. `fdisk -l /dev/sda` or `parted /dev/sda print` tells you what the partition table looks like. `LC_ALL=C dumpe2fs -h /dev/root | grep -e 'Block count:' -e 'Block size:'` (with `/dev/root` being replaced with the appropriate block device) tells the size of the filesystem.